# add the Stripe plugin to Nopcommerce

Tags: visual-studio, stripe-payments, nopcommerce

Stripe for 3.40 --> http://www.nopcommerce.com/p/1512/stripe-payment-plugin.aspx

So I noticed that when I download the Stripe plugin off the Nopcommerce.com site that the Stripe plugin for Nopcommerce v3.4 does not contain a project file(.csproj) to add the project to Visual studio.

Stripe for 2.65--> http://www.nopcommerce.com/p/638/stripe-payment-plugin.aspx

So I went and downloaded the Stripe plugin for Nopcommerce v2.65.  I noticed that this downloaded package does contain the Project file(.csproj) for adding to visual studio.

**1).** can I just use the older Stripe plugin with my new Nopcommerce version?

**2).** or and, does someone have a way to use the new Stripe plugin?

**3).** is there a better free shopping cart to use Stripe (asp.MVC)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plugin is provided without source code. I's alread compiled and ready for deployment. Hence you cannot add it to Visual Studio solution. So simply upload this plugin to your server and use it

Comment: So I can upload it to the root folder? or does it have to be inside the plugins folder? Thanks

Comment: All compiled plugins are located in the \Plugins directory on your server

Comment: ok, so i did that,  I uploaded and i installed stripe through my plugins.  It installs.  But when I try to do configure i get a "Were sorry, an Internal error occurred ... ..." page

Answer (score 0):

Rename the main folder by removing ''upload'' in the name it should read Payments.Stripe    try that and let me know!