# Configure stripe plugin for nopcommerce?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, web-hosting, stripe-payments, nopcommerce

Stripe for 3.40 --> http://www.nopcommerce.com/p/1512/stripe-payment-plugin.aspx

I have downloaded this. I zipped it and uploaded it to my plugins folder on my host in the NopCommerce installation installed.  I installed the plugin on the admin side of NopCommerce.  When I goto payment methods and try to Configure by hitting the configure button I get the error message.  As seen in the picture below.

[image]

Please help.

The stripe 3.40 plugin does not contain a .csproj file.  I had to directly upload it to my deployment.  So their is no way for me to debug my NopCommerce plugin in Visual Studio.  Is their a way to check my log when my project is deployed on Arvixe? or does someone know where I can get the source file for Visual studio?

This is another post where I recieved help for adding the stripe plugin.  I directly uploaded to plugins and then installed the plugin--> [add the Stripe plugin to Nopcommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746253/add-the-stripe-plugin-to-nopcommerce)

Comment: Could you check the log for some extra info?

Comment: I have updated my post.  Im not sure how or where to access logs on Arvixe hosting.

Comment: Just for the record, nopCommerce logs can be found at the administration backend under System/Logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin has a folder naming convention issue.  I figured out how to debug on the hosting platform and caught the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seams to be with folder name. This is what I did. 
I renamed the main folder to :  Payments.Stripe  and reloaded the plugin folder retried to click on ''configure'' and it worked. I entered my Stripe login ID (email for your Stripe account) and pasted the secret key that you can get in your account settings under API keys. Now I will test the checkout process using Stripe